# Chrome extension refuses to load script because of content security policy (trying to run babel in a chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

The react documentation points to this file as an example of using babel inline https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html

Even though it's not recommended for production, it would be helpful for me to develop faster if I could just write jsx for the time being in my chrome extension without having to compile myself. My issue is that if you try this you get an error in a chrome extension.

```
babel.min.js:1 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://unpkg.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-FN6NaNuBVCZD7+6eEydixs7VVD0vxTZKnwjth9yDpCC='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I've tried adding a content security policy to my chrome extension, but still get the same error: Here is my policy in my chrome extension manifest

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://unpkg.com; object-src 'self' 'sha256-FN6NaNuBVCZD7+6eEydixs7VVD0vxTZKnwjth9yDpCC='"
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't add `unsafe-inline` or a hashsum to `script-src` as suggested in the error message.

Comment: unsafe-inline is ignored by chrome extensions which is why I didn't add it. And I did add a hashsum in in my content security policy See `"'sha256-FN6NaNuBVCZD7+6eEydixs7VVD0vxTZKnwjth9yDpCC='"`

Comment: You didn't add it to `script-src`, which is what my comment points out.

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry. all of this is very new to me so I don't think I understood what you meant. Does my content sec policy not add to script-src? I thought that's what I was doing here: `"content_security_policy": "script-src...`?

Comment: You did add 'sha256-' to `object-src`, not to `script-src`

Comment: @granty aha okay. I totally misread how content sec policy works. I moved the sha up to be right after the script src and now it works. Thank you both. If anyone wants to leave it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: It's up to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), he is an author of right answer.